# Store rows of a matrix in variables - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, variables, matrix

I need to store each row of a matrix in vectors. If the matrix were to be something like:

```
 mtx = 0     3     4     
       3     0     1     
       4     1     0
```

The vectors would be:

```
vec1 = 0 3 4
vec2 = 3 0 1
vec3 = 4 1 0
```

How should I do it? Note that I don't know how many vectors there will be (at the time of code).

Comment: You may also check this: `rows = arrayfun(@(i)mtx(i,:),1:size(mtx,1),'uni',0)` :)

Comment: You probably don't _need_ to do that, and probably don't _want_ to because it will be messy to deal with those variables. You'd better use a cell array. Or much better, just use `mtx(1,:)` instead of `vec1`, `mtx(2,:)` instead of `vec2` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec1 = mtx(1,:)
vec2 = mtx(2,:)
vec3 = mtx(3,:)
```

If you have more vectors (an unknown number before runtime), can use a cell array

```
[m, n] = size(mtx);
for i = 1:m
    vec{i} = mtx(i, :);
end;
```

Now `vec{i}` contains the `i`-th row vector. You should really think if this is something you really want, as you can simply just use `mtx(i,:)`.

Comment: The problem with vec{i} = mtx(i, :) is that it stores in the same variable, I need it to be in different ones

Comment: @EveSmith so you want different names for each of your variables? If yes, I'd recommend to think about a change in design, or have a very good motivation why, as I see no reason to do this.

Comment: you're right! I was complicating. I've changed things now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cant dynamically create variables, without using [eval](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). The best way, would be creating [dynamically](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) fields of a structure, like this:

```
s = struct();

for rowi = 1:size(mtx, 1)
    s.(sprintf('var%d', rowi)) = mtx(rowi,:)
end
```

This gives:

```
s = 

    var1: [0 3 4]
    var2: [3 0 1]
    var3: [4 1 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the *"not recommended"* answer (that's why no one is posting it)!

```
mxt = [ 0     3     4;     
        3     0     1;     
        4     1     0];
for i = 1 : size(mxt,1)
   eval(['vec',num2str(i),' = mxt(',num2str(i),',:);']) 
end
```

gives you,

```
vec1 = [0     3     4];
vec2 = [3     0     1];
vec3 = [4     1     0];
```

Comment: if I wish to go through those vectors, how should I do it? If I use size (mtx, 1) I can know how many vectors there will be but how can I access them?

Comment: @EveSmith, Again access them with `eval` in a loop. See the help for `eval` that will help.

Comment: I've changed the code a bit, I think it's better now. Thank you